# How to reduce bandwith usage on php curl requests

Tags: php, curl

I had made a php app which works on an API but for sending requests to the API i use curl with a proxy and that proxy has a limited bandiwith, can someone please tell me about some practices which may help me to reduce bandwith.
P.S - I already know about CURLOPT_NOBODY which helps to reduce the bandwith usage a bit, but i need to save more bandwith.

My Current Code -

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My User Agent');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '209.XXX.XXX.XX:8081');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Need to see you're current code

Comment: my current code added